# Devise login does not redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I've asked this before but haven't got an answer, so reposting:

For some reason my Devise stopped redirecting me if I login to my application. (Yes, it worked at one point)

When I check my network tab it does show me a call to /user/sign_in and after that a call to localhost:3000 with the correct view(That should be loaded!). I can't think of changing everything to my code and wouldn't know in what part of the code it could cause problems, so I'm not posting that for now.

If I refresh my page I get a already_authenticated notification

I'm not using a custom controller, model. Only custom views.

Removing all javascript eliminates the problem but raises new Devise errors(I think devise needs jQuery): `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken`

My terminal output(I see a 302?)

```
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-13 09:24:00 +0100
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-13 09:24:00 +0100
Processing by DashboardController#index as HTML
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Group Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "groups".* FROM "groups" INNER JOIN "groups_users" ON "groups"."id" = "groups_users"."group_id" WHERE "groups_users"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]
  Rendered dashboard/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 23ms (Views: 15.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you leave the root URL on your route.rb?

```
root 'home#index'
```

Without it Devise will not redirect after login

Comment: I have a root; although it's not home#index ;)
'get "dashboard/index" root 'dashboard#index'
I had that from the start though. That's the page I see in my network tab of Chrome too. It's just not loading anew(Turbolinks??)

Answer (score -1):

Try generating the views with devise like so

```
rails generate devise:views
```

I had the same problem and

Answer (score -1):

Ok, go into the `config/initializers/cookie_verification_secret.rb` and cut the part that says

```
Rails.application.config.cookie_secret = 89384893...........
```

and paste it in your application.rb file and change it to config.cookie_secret = i235.....

for more info about this checkout the rails cast [http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise][1] Ryan explains it more.

Comment: I don't have a cookie_verification_secret.rb. Perhaps you're referring to an old Devise version(Seeing the cast is from 2010)